# How to define a manytomany relationship on the same table in objectionjs?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, objection.js

I have an article table, where an article can cite multiple articles. Each article can also have a single author.

Article model :

```js
class Article extends DefaultModel {
  static get tableName() {
    return "articles";
  }
  static get relationMappings() {
    return {
      author: {
        relation: DefaultModel.BelongsToOneRelation,
        modelClass: "Author",
        join: {
          from: "articles.authorId",
          to: "authors.id"
        }
      },
      mentions: {
        relation: DefaultModel.ManyToManyRelation,
        modelClass: "Article",
        join: {
          from: "articles.id",
          through: {
            from: "mentions.citingArticle",
            to: "mentions.citedArticle"
          },
          to: "articles.id"
        }
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Mention model :

```js
class Mention extends DefaultModel {
  static get tableName() {
    return "mentions";
  }
  static get idColumn() {
    return ["citingArticle", "citedArticle"];
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do, is insertGraph, the main article + the articles that are mentioned in it, here is what I have :

```js
async function insertData(fullArticle) {
  const articleTx = await transaction(Article.knex(), async tx => {
    const references = fullArticle.references
      .map(articleObj => {
          return {
            ...articleObj.article,
            author: articleObj.author
          };
      });

    const article = await Article.query(tx).insertGraph({
      ...fullArticle.article,
      author: fullArticle.author,
      mentions: references[0]
    });

    return article;
  });

  console.log(articleTx);
}
```

I know this is only inserting the main row + the first row, but I ran into multiple problems :

1. The mention model has a composite key, when I try to insert using the code above I get a `(node:5944) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: column "citedArticle" of relation "mentions" does not exist`.
2. I also got the same error when I try to add `"#id"` to the main article mentions relation, and `"#ref"` to the cited article,  and insert them in 2 different objects.
3. A third problem I ran into here, was a unique constraint on both the citing and the cited article authors. What if both of them were written by the same author? I have a unique string column in the authors table that isn't the id, when I tried to insert I got `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "author_isn"`. I'm not sure how I can update the row to reference the existing author id if that happens.

Comment: You dont have to set the Mention `idColumn` like that. That specifies the unique id column of the model database table.

Comment: @Rashomon but that table's pkey is composite of both ids, i took that declaration from here : https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/recipes/composite-keys.html#examples